# split large text file while unzipping (SharpZipLib)

Tags: c#, sharpziplib

I use the following code to unzip files (text files), which I then later read with a CSV parser into memory and manipulate as I deem fit. This works without problems but I have some fairly large files in some of the zip drives and because the rest of my code is paralellized it runs faster (and less error prone) with three 100MB files than with one 300MB file.

Here my current unzip code (using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll):

```
  public static void ExtractZipFile(string archiveFilenameIn, string password, string outFolder)
    {
        //unzip function based on SharpZipLib (external ref dll)
        ZipFile zf = null;
        try
        {
            FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(archiveFilenameIn);
            zf = new ZipFile(fs);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            {
                zf.Password = password;     
            }
            foreach (ZipEntry zipEntry in zf)
            {
                if (!zipEntry.IsFile)
                {
                    continue;           // Ignore directories
                }
                String entryFileName = zipEntry.Name;

                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];     // 4K is optimum
                Stream zipStream = zf.GetInputStream(zipEntry);

                String fullZipToPath = Path.Combine(outFolder, entryFileName);
                string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullZipToPath);
                if (directoryName.Length > 0)
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryName);
                using (FileStream streamWriter = File.Create(fullZipToPath))
                {
                    StreamUtils.Copy(zipStream, streamWriter, buffer);
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (zf != null)
            {
                zf.IsStreamOwner = true; // Makes close also shut the underlying stream
                zf.Close(); // Ensure we release resources
            }
        }
    }
```

I could obvioulsy just unzip, split and then read into memory but this seems like cumbersome. My question is:

Can I adjust the code above to write to different output files as soon as a threshold is passed? So if file limit is 100MB and unzipped total size 287MB I would like to extract to 3 files...